# Logic to add random time next to date using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code returns date in the format dd-MMM--YYYY (example: **13-Jan-2014**). I want to add a random time next to it. Something like: **13-Jan-2014 03:00 PM** or **13-Jan-2014 03:00 AM**. What can I add to get the desired output? Thanks.

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

function DateAndTimeFormate(date) {
    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
                     "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var date = new Date(date);
    return date.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[(date.getMonth() + 1)] + '-' +  date.getFullYear();
}

var datewithformate = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));

//Start date
$("#time").val(datewithformate)
```

Comment: `date.setTime(1332403882588);` ?

Comment: Thank you for replying. But can you be more specific? In terms of where I need to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this-

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

function DateAndTimeFormate(date) {
    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
    "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var date = new Date(date);
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var t = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    var hour = (hours % 12).toString().length == 1 ? '0' + (hours % 12) : (hours % 12);
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var minute = minutes.toString().length == 1 ? minutes + '0' : minutes;
    return date.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[(date.getMonth())] + '-' +  date.getFullYear() + ' ' + hour + ':' + minute + ' ' + t;
}

var datewithformate = DateAndTimeFormate(randomDate(new Date(0000, 0, 0), new Date()));

//Start date
$("#time").val(datewithformate)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Luhtfzxj/3/

Comment: Thank you. But how do you add AM/PM in a 12 hour format?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh There is another bug in the code monthNames[(date.getMonth() + 1)] will produce incorrect month names and an undefined for december, because date.getMonth() starts with 0 and ends with 11.

Comment: @axel.michel Thanks. I saw that. I took it from OP. May be some logic OP has put.

Comment: Thank you. We're almost there. I just need to add a '0' before the hour. Example: Instead of 8:30 am, how can I make it 08:30 am or 08:30 pm?

Comment: Just one more error. For times like, 02:30 am, it is showing 02:3 am. What's the fix for that?

Comment: @AnanSrivastava Check it now.

Answer (score 1):

You already have a method which produces a random date time, it is only a question of formatting.

```
function randomDate(start, end) {
    return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()));
}

function DateAndTimeFormate(date) {
    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    var date = new Date(date);
    // get the time 
    var time = date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', hour12: true });
    // to fulfill your requirements some further manipulations
    var ampm = time.slice(-2);
    time = parseInt(time);
    if (time < 10) { time = '0' + time }
    time += ':00 ' + ampm; 
    return date.getDate() + '-' + 
        monthNames[(date.getMonth())] + '-' +  
        date.getFullYear() + ' ' + 
        time; 
}
```

[Example is here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpo9L4ne/1/).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. But for me, it's always giving 1-Jan-1970 05:00 AM. It's not randomizing. Any clue why?

Comment: @AnanSrivastava the example link is not working? Works fine for me

Comment: You're spot on about that 'undefined' error. What is the fix for that?

Comment: Look at the code, monthNames[date.getMonth()] would be correct.

Comment: The example link works just fine. But for me, in my code, it always gives 1-Jan-1970 05:00 AM. What are we missing here?

Comment: I do not see your code, if the example is working, why don't you copy these functions 1:1 in your code - replacing the existing ones? If this is the case, there must be another error which is not related to the provided code. Have a look at the error console, or provide a fiddle to let us look.

Answer (score 0):

```
function DateAndTimeFormate(date) {
    var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
        "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
    ];
    var date1 = new Date(date);
    date1.setTime(1332403882588);
    return date1.getDate() + '-' + monthNames[(date1.getMonth() + 1)] + '-' + date1.getFullYear() + ' ' + date1.getHours() + ':' + date1.getMinutes();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do you add AM/PM in a 12 hour format?

Comment: i think there are way too many other answer already ..hahah :) @axel.michel has a good one

Answer (score 0):

You can use .setSeconds(x) method to add a random time with x is random number falls in range of 0 <= x < 86400. For example:

```
var date = new Date('13-Jan-2014');
// date = Mon Jan 13 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
var randomSeconds = Math.floor((Math.random() * 86400));
// randomSenconds = 53135
date.setSeconds(randomSenconds)
// date = Mon Jan 13 2014 14:45:35 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)
```

I think this javascript library http://momentjs.com/ is helpful for you to manipulate/format/... dates that you don't need to write long/complicated code like the code in your question. For example:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // January 13th 2017, 2:17:37 pm
```

Comment: I will look at that library. Thank you.

Comment: Using 20k of javascript to format something like 00:00? moment.js is a real useful library for advanced date manipulations and calculations but for writing a random AM/PM it is a bit oversized.